# Punctuation and Control characters in Excel VBA API calls

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel VBA program which pulls my inventory via an API call from my POS.
The descriptions have characters that get changed during the get call.
For example:

```
    " becomes \
    / becomes \/
    < becomes &lt;
```

Is there a reference list somewhere that gives the full breakdown?
I want to be able to make bulk changes to the descriptions and then upload them back, but the API Post doesn't always like those changes, so I want to try to catch them before the API post.

Comment: A bit more info (including the relevant VBA) would be useful here.  We have no idea exactly what you're doing to prep the call to the API, or to handle the response.